# Where are the files for the Aqua UI located for OS X 10.4 Tiger?

Tags: macos, powerpc

I am wanting to compile the raw files for UI elements (traffic lights, buttons, scroll bars, text boxes, etc.) for several versions throughout the history of OS X, and I have been able to find the files for Yosemite and Snow Leopard, but I cannot find the files for Tiger. Is there some list of paths for the UI elements of OS X versions that I am not googling precisely enough for? I have tried basically every combination of "os x tiger ui images location".

Answer (score 1):

It might be a bit late, but try here:

```
/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemAppearance.bundle/Contents/Resources
```

That should be filled with CAR files. You can use an app like [ThemeEngine](https://github.com/jslegendre/ThemeEngine) (forked from [here](https://github.com/alexzielenski/ThemeEngine)) to look at everything. I don’t know if ThemeEngine even supports Tiger, but it should do something, at least.

Comment: There is no bundle with the name "SystemAppearance" in CoreServices.

Comment: Hm, they must have changed it. I guess that makes sense. There should be something in `CoreServices`, because that's where all the system things live.